# How to open a PDF-file using default application on Windows with QProcess?

Tags: qt4

I'm trying to open a pdf file in acrobat-reader using

```
QProcess::startDetached("start c:\\temp\\mypdf.pdf")
```

no success :-(

If I type the same in a console acrobat starts fine and loads my PDF file.

What am I missing?

I'm using Qt4.8.4 on Windows 7

**EDIT**

it works using:

```
QProcess::startDetached( "cmd /Q /C \"start c:\\temp\\report.pdf\"" );
```

but black console window appears for a short time - which is not nice.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You might want to look into QDesktopServices. QProcess starts a program, but has not understanding of the underlying system. QDesktopServices does.

Comment: +1: Great! now QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl::fromUserInput("c:/temp/report.pdf")); works fine